# Table locking in a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2, table-locking

Let's say I've written plpgsql function that does the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foobar (_foo_data_id bigint)
RETURNS bigint AS $$
BEGIN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_foobar;

    CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_foobar AS
    SELECT *
    FROM foo_table ft
    WHERE ft.foo_data_id = _foo_data_id;

    -- more SELECT queries on unrelated tables

    -- a final SELECT query that invokes tmp_foobar

END;
```

**First question:**

If I simultaneously invoked this function twice, is it possible for the second invocation of `foobar()` to drop the `tmp_foobar` table  while the first invocation of `foobar()` is still running?

I understand that `SELECT` statements create an `ACCESS SHARE` lock, but will that lock persist until the `SELECT` statement completes or until the implied `COMMIT` at the end of the function?

**Second question:**

If the latter is true, will the second invocation of `foobar()` indefinitely re-try `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_foobar;` until the lock is dropped or will it fail at some point?

Comment: I wouldn't use a temp table for this to begin with. I wouldn't be surprised if a single (large) SELECT was faster. Are you coming from a SQL Server background?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My question is a small-scale example and isn't representative of our real code. The reason why we're using temp tables is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simultaneously invoke a function twice, it means you're using two separate sessions to do so.  Temporary tables are not shared between sessions, so the second session would not "see" tmp_foobar from the first session, and there would be no interaction.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html#AEN70605 ("Temporary tables").

Locks persist until the end of the transaction (regardless of how you acquire them; exception are advisory locks, but that's not what you're doing.)

The **second question** does not need an answer, because the premise is false.

One more thing.  It might be useful to create indexes on that temporary table of yours, and ANALYZE it; that might cause the final query to be faster.